# How close to spells are infusions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, artificer

The *Eberron Campaign Setting* on Infusions says that infusions "function just like spells and follow all the rules for spells" (31). However, it also says, "An artificer cannot automatically use a spell trigger or spell completion item if the equivalent spell appears on his infusion list," then says that "an artificer must still employ the Use Magic Device skill to use" wands of spells that appear on the artificer's infusions list.

What does this means for an artificer that wants to create and activate magic items directly incorporating infusions? For example, can an artificer create a *wand of personal weapon augmentation*, and, if so, must the artificer make a Use Magic Device skill check to activate that wand?

Answer (score 3):

> For example, can an artificer create a wand of personal weapon augmentation[?]

Yes

> **[I]f so, must the artificer make a Use Magic Device skill check to activate that wand?**

### No.

While an artificer must use a Use Magic Device check to operate even a Wand of Light that he creates (confusingly), for the purpose of creating magic items the distinction between infusions and spells only seems to matter when an infusion which shares a name for a spell is placed into a spell completion or spell trigger item.

> An artiﬁcer cannot automatically use a spell trigger or spell completion item if the equivalent spell appears on his infusion list. [ECS p.31]

That is, **if** an infusion and a spell share a name and function (like the example of light), **then** the artificer cannot automatically use a spell trigger or spell completion item with that spell or infusion. (Literally speaking, it seems the game system does a "check" to see if infusion X is "equivalent" to any spell in the game not on the artificer's infusion list. If the check finds an equivalent, then the artificer must use Use Magic Device to activate the spell trigger or spell completion item.)

> What does this means for an artificer that wants to create and activate magic items directly incorporating infusions?

Ignoring for a moment wands and scrolls, a creative artificer could create a **Tab of Personal Weapon Augmentation**, standard action to activate, usable 3 times per day, and distribute those throughout his party. Whilst an artificer is held to certain standards regarding the usage of spell completion and spell trigger items, no one in his party is, and none of the limitations regarding infusions limit their eligibility as possible magic items. Indeed, in lieu of a specific rule regarding magic items, infusions "function just like spells and follow all the rules for spells[.]" *Rings of Spell Storing* or *Imbue Familiar with Spell Like Ability* (presuming a familiar or item familiar) are certainly valid targets for various infusions, as well.

Or, re-stated:

### So long as an infusion is "equivalent" to any spell in the game, the artificer  must make a *Use Magic Device* check to activate a spell trigger or spell completion item containing such an infusion.

Comment: So, yes, such an item *can* be created? I'm unclear on the phrasing here. Feel free to break up my question if that's useful. (Also, even without the *RC*, the *DMG* says that "the casting time of a spell is the time required to activate the same power in an item, whether it’s a scroll, a wand, or a pair of boots, unless the item description specifically states otherwise" (213). I've always taken this to mean that, for example, even under the core rules it still takes 1 hour to employ a *wand of identify*, the standard action activation of wands being for specific and exceptional wands. )

Comment: Your DMG citation has effectively reminded me that am but a humble human. I don't know how I have been playing this game for so long without having that shoved into my face years ago. A weakness of a well experienced play group, I suppose? Either way, **thank you** for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Don't be *too* humbled. It's a hideous sentence, and it really can be read either way. `;-)`